# flask can log in but when redirect to login_required decorating url it failed

Tags: flask, session, flask-login

I have define a User class inheriting from UserMixin

```
class User(UserMixin):
    ID = 1

    def __init__(self, username, password, email, role):
        self.id = User.ID
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.role = role
        User.ID += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

    def verify_password(self, raw_password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, raw_password)

class AdminSet(object):
    admin1 = User(username='admin1', password=generate_password_hash('admin1', method='pbkdf2:sha1', salt_length=5),
                  email='admin1@admin.com', role=0)
    admin2 = User(username='admin2', password=generate_password_hash('admin2', method='pbkdf2:sha1', salt_length=5),
                  email='admin2@admin.com', role=1)
    admin_list = [admin1, admin2]

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, user):
        cls.admin_list.append(user)

    @classmethod
    def commit(cls, **kwargs):
        admin = User(**kwargs)
        cls.admin_list.append(admin)

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, user_id):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def searchID(cls, id):
        for admin in cls.admin_list:
            if admin.id == id:
                return admin
        return None

    @classmethod
    def queryFirst(cls, username):
        for admin in cls.admin_list:
            if admin.username == username:
                return admin
        return None
```

this is my login url and main.index

```py
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('password:', form.password.data)
        # try:
        user = AdminSet.queryFirst(form.username.data)
        if user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            print("same")
            login_user(user)
            print(current_user)
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
        else:
            print("different")
            flash('wrong')
        # except:
        #     print("exception")
        #     flash('用户名或密码错误')
    return render_template('auth/login.html', form=form)

@main.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('main/index.html')
```

and what I got from console is below when log in:

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "POST /login?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 -
same
<User 'admin1'>
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/login/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/login/demo.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/login/loaders.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/js/login/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/js/login/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/layui/layui.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/js/login/stopExecutionOnTimeout.js?t=1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:10] "GET /static/js/login/Particleground.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2022 00:37:11] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

you can see the user has been successfully loaded and printed, and execute the code`return redirect(url_for('main.index'))`

then the page was  redirected to the `auth.login` again.

I didn't choose database for some reasons.I don't whether there is something wrong  with my code, and I have used debugger to check the login_user() function, but I didn't get any useful information.

Comment: i think you are missing the `user_loader` callback, you can check `flask-login`'s documentation

Comment: !Thank you, I just  changed the `user_id` passed into `user_loader`into `int(user_id)` and then it works normally! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, The problem is the mistake in `user_loader` call back

This is the initial verison

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return AdminSet.searchID(user_id)
```

with a small change on user_id

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return AdminSet.searchID(int(user_id))
```

it works fine!